# shortcut key to go alternate file in Aptana 3 (ubuntu)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, aptana3

Please tell me the shortcut key to go alternate file in Aptana3. For ex. i have a controller and a action named hello.Now i want to shift from controller to hello.rhtml. I tried Shift + ctrl + Alt + Down. But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now we don't have any short cut keys for this. but we can achieve this by going as follows

commands --> Rails --> Go To --> Go To Alternate File

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to switch over opened files in Aptana? Am I right?
You can have that easy with ,

```
Ctrl + Tab
```

if you want to go next file 
or

```
Ctrl + Shift + Tab
```

if you want switch to previous file.

You can adjust that under Preferences / General / Keys and : Previous Editor(Aptana) and Next Editor (Aptana)

Comment: I have one controller with action hello. I want to open the view page hello.rhtml using shortcut keys.

Comment: What you can do is Ctrl + Shift + R/2 then Jump to file just type in "hello" and that way you may open file you are looking for, also please make your question more specyfic before you downvote my answer.

Comment: ctrl + shift + R is to open a resource. Everybody knows that. I am asking about to shift from controller to view. In aptana2 we have shift + ctrl + v. but the same is not working in aptana3. I am asking the shortcut for that.

Comment: Well, I've not been using aptana for ruby-on-rails so thats probably why I didnt understood your question correctly, I've searched docs and over the net for this answer and there is no info on this anywhere. Maybe the only option is a question to devs and if they confirm that this feature is not implemented we should post a ticket so sooner or later they make it.